# Why mediapipe package unable to install in py version 3.11?

Tags: python

mediapipe package unable to install in windows11 py version 3.11, pip version up to date
( ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe)-- Error

help me out regarding package issue

Comment: According to the [list of downloadable files on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files), there is no (binary) package for Python 3.11 on Windows. You'll either have to change to an older Python version or change platform (Linux and macOS seem to be supported). Or [file an issue with the developers](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues).

Answer (score 0):

When you cannot install a package from PyPI, you should look directly on PyPI the available distribution files. Here on that [page](https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/#files), we can see that no source package is available and that there is no package for Python 3.11 for Windows. The best available is for 3.10, provided you have a 64 bits Python installation.

You are left with a few options:

- install a 3.10 version and use that one for mediapipe
- clone a source copy from GitHUB and try to install from there (unsure of the complexity of the task...)
- use a Windows System for Linux (Ubuntu on Windows), install a Python 3.11 there and then install mediapipe on that install. The downside is that it can be used only in the WSL subsystem